# Multiple bluetooth devices connected to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

I like to run with my [The House of Marley Positive Vibration 2 Wireless Headphones](https://www.thehouseofmarley.com/positive-vibration2-wireless-headphones.html), I've been thinking about getting [Polar H10 Heart Rate Sensor](https://www.polar.com/en/products/accessories/H10_heart_rate_sensor).

My question is - will these two devices both work at the same time with an iPhone SE (I'd upgrade if necessary)? I'm usually streaming music with Spotify and would love to receive data from HR rate sensor at the same time.

Will the iPhone battery last less with more than one bluetooth device connected?

What if I keep adding bluetooth devices? Is there a limit?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** they will work at the same time! Apple recognizes that one is a health device and the other is a listening device so u are able to use both at the and time!! I speak from experience because I sometimes have 3 devices connected at the same time (Headphones, Apple Watch, Health Device)